# Hibernate ClassCastException org.hibernate.type.SerializableType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jodatime, h2

I have an odd exception appearing when I try to run a unit test. Here is the stack trace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: testPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
     ... more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.SerializableType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildVersionProperty(PropertyFactory.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor29.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    ... 43 more
```

Here are the libraries and frameworks that I'm using:

1. JPA 2.0
2. org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.5.Final
3. com.h2database:h2:1.4.188
4. junit:junit:4.11
5. Intellij IDE (I'm just running the test here)
6. org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:4.3.5.Final

Well, I bet anyone who looks at this wants to see the persistense.xml file so here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

There are many classes here so I've cut them out to keep things readable

```
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL;INIT=create schema if not exists test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The unit test is basic. It just finds a record by a value. Here is the code:

```
@Test
  public void testFindByNaturalKeyReturnsBusinessUnit() {
    final BusinessUnit businessUnit = mock(BusinessUnit.class);
    assertThat(businessUnitDao.findByNaturalKey(businessUnit.getNaturalKey()).getId(), is(businessUnit.getId()));
  }
```

Finally, the entity is really complex. I'm not sure if posting the code is going to help. I guess that there is a relationship at fault in the entity so I'm looking into that.

Comment: Is there a field called "version" in your entity? If so, can you show the mapping for it?

Comment: No, there isn't a column named version. But  there is another dependency in the application that I didn't mention. It is org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:4.3.5.Final which deals with auditing and versioning. I think that you are on to something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there is an answer. The entity class used JodaTime for some of the fields. This required the persistence.xml file to have some additional properties set.

Example of the JodaTime fields:

```
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "active_date")
private org.joda.time.DateTime activeDate;
```

Finally, the fixed persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

There are many classes here so I've cut them out to keep things readable

```
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL;INIT=create schema if not exists test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes" value="true"/>
            <property name="jadira.usertype.databaseZone" value="jvm"/>
            <property name="jadira.usertype.javaZone" value="jvm"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: In case of Java8 it might be missing `org.hibernate:hibernate-java8` dependency which causes same error on LocalDateTime. It causes the same error message.